# Proving that an element of the image of a Lie Algebra representation is nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie Algebra with basis $X,Y$ and a Lie bracket characterised by: $[X,Y]=Y$

I‘m supposed to show that for every $n$-dim representation, i.e. $\rho: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(\mathbb{C}^n)$, $\rho([X,Y])=[\rho( X), \rho( Y)]$, it must hold that $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}: \rho(Y)^n=0$.

This is possible by considering the eigenvectors of $\rho(X)$. Because:

$$
\rho(X)v=\lambda v \wedge [\rho(X),\rho(Y)]v=\rho(Y)v \\
\Rightarrow \rho(X)\rho(Y)v=(\lambda +1)\rho(Y)v 
$$

Which means that $\rho(Y)v$ is also an eigenvector, but since eigenvectors with different eigenvalues are linearily independent this can’t go on forever and $\rho(Y)^nv=0$.
The desired result would follow if the eigenvectors of $\rho(X)$ would span the space, but I dont see why that would hold. What am I missing?

Comment: Or have I just forgotten a linear algebra fact, that just states exactly that?

Comment: Yes, let $A=\rho(Y)$ and $B=\rho(X)$ and use this linear algebra result from the duplicate. We have $AB-BA=[A,B]$ because $\rho$ is a representation. But note that we need characteristic zero.